# freeCodeCamp Twitchtv APi Project: AJAX call error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, twitch

I am trying to make a [freeCodeCamp Intermediate Front End Development project](https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/use-the-twitchtv-json-api) which needs me to make use of Twitchtv API.

---

Currently, this code gives errors. When I analysed it with JSHint, it says that I cannot put a function inside a loop.

Code:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  var streamers = [
    "ESL_SC2",
    "OgamingSC2",
    "cretetion",
    "freecodecamp",
    "storbeck",
    "habathcx",
    "RobotCaleb",
    "noobs2ninjas"
  ];
  var htm = "";
  for (i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++) {
    var url = "https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/channels/" + streamers[i];
    console.log(url);
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("Success!");
        console.log(url);
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log("Error!");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Now when I remove functions from the loop, it gives an error that data is not defined.

Code:

```js
function myFunction(data) {
  console.log("Success!");
  console.log(url);
  console.log(data);
}

function myFunction2(data = null) {
  console.log("Error!");
}
$("document").ready(function() {
  var streamers = [
    "ESL_SC2",
    "OgamingSC2",
    "cretetion",
    "freecodecamp",
    "storbeck",
    "habathcx",
    "RobotCaleb",
    "noobs2ninjas"
  ];
  var htm = "";
  for (i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++) {
    var url = "https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/channels/ESL_SC2"; //+streamers[i];
    console.log(url);
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: "json",
      success: myFunction(data),
      error: myFunction2(data)
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

I got API from [here](https://wind-bow.glitch.me/)

I want to know how to remove these problems from my code:

- The first code is giving Error.
- The second code is giving data undefined.
- The ajax call is NOT executing the function for success *anyway*.
- Instead of ajax call executed during each iteration of the for loop, it executes after the loop is over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here is a working example for your ajax call

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
        var streamers = [
            "ESL_SC2",
            "OgamingSC2",
            "cretetion",
            "freecodecamp",
            "storbeck",
            "habathcx",
            "RobotCaleb",
            "noobs2ninjas"
        ];
        for (i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/channels/"+streamers[i],
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp', // added data type
                success: function(res) {
                    console.log(res);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```